# How do you call modules dynamically with a namespace import from index file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to set up the front-end to an application that dynamically calls components based on a clients needs. So we have an index file with three components being imported `ComponentOne ComponentTwo ComponentThree`

I import it like so, `import * as components from '../components'`

Then in my render method, I have a prop (passed from the parent component) called componentString which essentially is used to check if the component should exist on this users version of the site.

For example, this component string would be 'ComponentOne'. I have a wrapper that checks if the specific component exists on the back-end for the users and then should call and render that component.

My question is how can I use this string to essentially call the component.

I have tried things like `<components[componentString] />` or `<components.componentString />` or `{component[componentString]}` and finally `{components.componentString]}`. All do not work, essentially I would just like the result to be equal to `<ComponentOne />` but calling something like `<componentString />` does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the official [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) I would say you'd need to write it like below. Basically you need to add it as a `CapitalizedComponent` before trying to render it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { PhotoStory, VideoStory } from './stories';

const components = {
  photo: PhotoStory,
  video: VideoStory
};

function Story(props) {
  // Correct! JSX type can be a capitalized variable.
  const SpecificStory = components[props.storyType];
  return <SpecificStory story={props.story} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
// Outside class/function
const MyComponent = Components.componentString;

// ....render

<MyComponent />
```